# How to calculate a rank of a map?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The rank of a $f: M\rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are differentialble manifolds, at a point $p\in M$ is the rank of the derivative of $f$ at $p.$

Now I want to show that $F:\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ such that $F(x,y,z)=(yz, zx, xy, x^2-y^2,x^2+y^2+z^2-1)$ has rank $3$ at ever point.

However I do not see how to show this given the definition of rank.

Comment: Have you computed the derivative of a point $p\in \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Have you computed the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at some $(x,y,z)\neq (0,0,0)$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito now I got it thanks!

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 now I got it thanks!

Comment: You could write up an answer yourself and then post it.